# How to launch RSS reader app from Safari?

Tags: ios, safari, rss, url-scheme

I have an iOS `RSS` reader app and want to add a new feature to it - be able to launch my app from `Safari` if the user clicks the `rss` feed button on a web page.

As I know - launching is possible via `URL-scheme`, but what kind of `URL-scheme` do I need?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved this issue with the help of `feed` URL scheme.
Moreover, you have to register additional URL type with the app name.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this link: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/DocumentInteraction_TopicsForIOS/Articles/RegisteringtheFileTypesYourAppSupports.html

It seems like what you are searching for

Comment: Thanks, but your solution fits for the document opening flow, for xml based feeds it doesn't work.